# Best strategy for true vault hunter mode

Tags: borderlands-2

Hey I recently beat borderlands-2 and was getting the absolute hell beat out of me till I slowed down but I still can't get past the first couple side quests

Ex: assassinating the assassins. On the first playthrough took all down In less than 8 mins but now can't even get past the second assassin.

So guys any help is very appreciated

Please help by leaving: tips,strategies,info,farm spots

Comment: Have you tried playing multiplayer for more exp.

Comment: This is too broad to be properly answerable.  You want a walkthrough for an entire difficulty level.  If you want to limit it to just the assassin section, we can probably give you some advice on how to get past that.

Answer (score 2):

In Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode, you must use the right elemental weapons.

Shock against shields (blue bar)
Fire against flesh (red bar)--> note some fleshy enemies are resistant to fire, like incenerators and fire skags.
Acid against armored enemies( yellow bar)

you can also use slag weapons to apply slag effect on enemies, then switch to another weapon for x2 damage.

In borderlands 2, there is no need to farm xp, simply doing all the side quest yeld enough xp to stay ahead in levels.

Also remember to upgrade your gear constantly, even legendaries become worthless in 5-6 levels, so it is important to have your gear to match your current level, even white items can sometimes be better than few levels lower green and blue items.

Regarding the quest you are stuck in, keep your distance, second assassin has very poor accuracy, but strong attack power. By constantly kiting him, you can avoid almost all damage completely, just stay on the move to avoid his explosive attacks, destroy the shields with shock weapon, apply slag and then use fire to burn him alive.

Comment: "Also remember to upgrade your gear constantly": How do you upgrade, there is no option whatsoever to upgrade in this game at all.